# Does the value of the voltmeter change after closing the circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis

At the start the voltmeter reads a specific value (I guess it is the value of the voltage of R2, right?)

Question:

If circuit closes, what value does the voltmeter read?

My answer is: It does not change!

Is my argumentation correct?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *is my argumentation correct?*

No.

This assumes the voltmeter has infinite input impedance: -

- When the switch is open, the voltmeter reads the voltage across R1.

<sub>R3 is irrelevant in this situation and might as well be a short circuit.</sub>

- When the switch is closed, the voltmeter reads the voltage across R2

Comment: @ Andy aka, Short circuit? R3 is a constant resistor that is obviously present in both situations;  so it cannot be a short circuit.

Comment: When the switch is open. Read what I said.

Comment: @MadSpaces when the switch is closed, the volt meter is connected across R2

Comment: I have read it carefully... and you know that very well. This is a circuit of three resistors and a switch where only the state of the switch can be changed (resistances are constant). There are two situations - the switch is 'off' and the switch is 'on'. So, what I tried to said is that there is no sense to talk about a situation when R3 = 0 and the voltage source is short connected.

Comment: @Andyaka - It would be nice if both of you could play just a wee bit more gently. Andy implied something without stating it explicitly. He could have been clearer if he wanted easy understanding by everyone. However, CF's statement that what is said "makes no sense" to speak of R3 being 0 - it makes sense in the area that Andy was speaking about - but not for the switch closed situation. Both you gentlemen know much. It would be nice if you could both be on the same team as much as you can manage and be a bit slower in being annoyed by the other guy.

Comment: @Circuit fantasist - It would be nice if both of you could play just a wee bit more gently. Andy implied something without stating it explicitly. He could have been clearer if he wanted easy understanding by everyone. However, CF's statement that what is said "makes no sense" to speak of R3 being 0 - it makes sense in the area that Andy was speaking about - but not for the switch closed situation. Both you gentlemen know much. It would be nice if you could both be on the same team as much as you can manage and be a bit slower in being annoyed by the other guy.

Comment: Andy - might I suggest you make the conditions under which R3 may as well be 0 clearer. I know what you mean BUT I also felt on 1st reading that it was not conveyed wholly clearly. || I note that it may be worth saying that this cct is probably trying to be tricky on purpose. It relies on Rmetter >> R3 cor meter to almost read VR1 accurately (low by R3/(R3+R_meter) . BUT it is no better than using the switch as a straight changeover to transfer the meter from one to other. In both cases the meter polarity swaps which is liable to be non useful.

Comment: Let's simplify by calling the bottom terminal of V ground.  R1 and R3 form a constant voltage divider setting the voltage at the negative voltmeter terminal to V*R3/(R1+R3) (we'll say V'), and this doesn't change based on switch position.  Closing the switch changes the voltage at the positive voltmeter terminal between V and 0.  The voltage measured will switch from V-V' to -V'.